# HTML5 required attribute for select in form and table seems not working

Tags: html, forms, select, html-table, required

I want to implement `required` attribute in my `<select>` tag.
I have emptied the first `<value>` of the first `<option>`.
Though, the required attribute seems not working..

```
<select name="section" id="section" style="width: 250px;" required>
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Section --</option>
    <option value="ict">ICT & MULTIMEDIA</option>
    <option value="net">DATA COMM & NETWORKING</option>
</select>
```

Prior to that, I put the `<select>` tag in `<form>` that is in `<table>` tag.

```
<table>
<form>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select..>
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

I am running my code in the latest version of Google Chrome; 45.0.2454.101

Comment: Why do you think that it is not working? How do you expect it is working? Check this very simple expamle. Attribute works when you click Submit button. http://jsfiddle.net/k5h3eLco/

Comment: @ViktorKireev I have made some searching on the web but I still couldn't get the answer and solution of why is it not working. I expect it working exactly as your given example.

Comment: Correct your HTML - put form tag outside your table tag.

Comment: @ViktorKireev Done. Still not working.

Comment: Please provide us with complete HTML in jsfiddle as I did in first comment. It will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `value=""` from your first option, and you can set `selected="selected"` as just `selected`.

Comment: Done. It remains the same. `<select name="section" id="section" style="width: 250px;" required>
    <option selected>-- Select Section --</option>
    <option value="ict">ICT & MULTIMEDIA</option>
    <option value="net">DATA COMM & NETWORKING</option>
</select>`

Comment: Try adding `aria-required="true"` after your `required`?

Comment: Like this right? `<select name="section" id="section" style="width: 250px;" required aria-required="true">
         <option selected>-- Select Section --</option>
         <option value="ict">ICT & MULTIMEDIA</option>
        </select>`   Still not working..

Comment: Then I would suggest [this](http://codepen.io/jakebown/pen/VvmoXB) for validation.